# laravel foreach return Multi arrays

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-5, foreach

My foreach return a different array when there is different $Tag 
i need My Foreach to return all tasks in 1 array not multi because I can't sort them correctly

```
@foreach ($Paths->pathtags as $Tag)
   {{ $Tag->name }}
     @foreach ($Tag->Tasks as $Task)

       {{ $Task->id   }}
       {{ $Task->name }}
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

in Example

Tag Name  : Tag1 , Tag2
Task      : id 11
Task Name : Task number 1
................................................

Tag Name  : Tag4 , Tag6
Task      : id 7
Task Name : Task number 2

.................
Tag Name  : Tag4 , Tag6
Task      : id 8
Task Name : Task number 3

So if the Tags is different I can't sort them only tasks with same tags 
is able to be sort

Comment: This is very confusing... Could you give some more info, how you retrieve the data and what you're ctually trying to accomplish? `foreach` doesn't return the multiple arrays... that's the way you built your data structure or retrieve the data from the DB

Comment: ^ I can't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish, but it sounds like this might be a candidate for one or more helpers built-in with Laravel collections. For example, [the `flatten` function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-flatten).

Comment: Give an example of the actual behavior and the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to flatten the relationship Tasks.
You can override the toArray function in your model, so you will format the returned value in your controller:

In your Controller:

`$results = YourModel::with('Tasks')->get()
$Paths = $results->toArray();`

In your Model

`public function toArray()
{
    return [
        ...
        'taskId' => $this->Tasks->id,
        'taskName' => $this->Tasks->name,
    ];
}`